# Create and classify a row based on column values

Tags: sql, sas

I am attempting to assign a classification to a row of data based on whether certain values exist. Utilizing the sample code below I have gotten to a place where I've gotten stuck.

```
proc sql;

create table test 
(id char(4),
task char(4),
id2 char(4),
status char(10),
seconds num);


insert into test
values('1','A','1','COMP',15)
values('1','B','2','WORK',20)
values('1','C','3','COMP',50)
values('1','D','3','COMP',null)
values('2','A','1','COMP',15)
values('2','B','2','COMP',520)
values('2','C','2','COMP',NULL)
values('2','D','3','COMP',221)
values('2','E','3','COMP',null)
values('2','F','3','COMP',null);

proc sql;
create table test2 as 
select 
ID,
ID2,
STATUS,
SUM(SECONDS) AS SECONDS,
sum(case when task='A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS A,
sum(case when task='B' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS B,
sum(case when task='C' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS C,
sum(case when task='D' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS D,
sum(case when task='E' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS E,
sum(case when task='F' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS F
from
test
GROUP BY
ID,
ID2,
STATUS
;
quit;
```

Ultimately I would like to classify each row that gets created in the second step 'test2' to have a column that looks to the values in each lettered column(A-F) and Label them as such. So when the Row has a 1 in Column A only, it would be labeled 'A' but when a row has a 1 in multiple columns like 'D', 'E' and 'F' I would like it to be labeled as D_E_F.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best way to do this is in a DATA STEP:

```
data test3;
format classifier $32.;
set test2;
array vars[6] A B C D E F;

classifier = "";
do i=1 to 6;
    if vars[i] then
        classifier = catx("_",classifier,vname(vars[i]));
end;
drop i;
run;
```

I create a character variable `CLASSIFIER` with length 32.

I define an array that groups the columns A through F.  This allows me to loop over those columns easily.

Initialize the `CLASSIFIER` variable.

Loop over the array.  If the value =1, then add the name of the variable to the `CLASSIFIER` string.

`CATX(delim,str1,str2)` concatenates `str1` and `str2` with the `delim` in the middle.  It also removes whitespace.

`VNAME(array[i])` returns the variable name of the variable pointed to by `array[i]`.

Finally remove the `i` loop variable, unless you really want it in your output.

Comment: this works so cleanly! the explanation of what you did was very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I know it is ugly, but you can do it with *CASE* statements accumulating the wanted result in another field. You have the SQL Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b6d0f/5).

Note that if it is possible that the concatenation is empty you will have to check this condition to avoid performing the *substring*.

```
select 
  ID,
  ID2,
  STATUS,
  SUM(SECONDS) AS SECONDS,
  sum(case when task='A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS A,
  sum(case when task='B' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS B,
  sum(case when task='C' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS C,
  sum(case when task='D' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS D,
  sum(case when task='E' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS E,
  sum(case when task='F' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS F,  
  substring(
  case when sum(case when task='A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1 then '_A' else '' end 
  + case when sum(case when task='B' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1 then '_B' else '' end 
  + case when sum(case when task='C' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1 then '_C' else '' end 
  + case when sum(case when task='D' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1 then '_D' else '' end 
  + case when sum(case when task='E' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1 then '_E' else '' end 
  + case when sum(case when task='F' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1 then '_F' else '' end,  
  2, len(case when sum(case when task='A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1 then '_A' else '' end 
  + case when sum(case when task='B' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1 then '_B' else '' end 
  + case when sum(case when task='C' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1 then '_C' else '' end 
  + case when sum(case when task='D' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1 then '_D' else '' end 
  + case when sum(case when task='E' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1 then '_E' else '' end 
  + case when sum(case when task='F' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1 then '_F' else '' end) - 1) as wantedOutput
from
test
GROUP BY
ID,
ID2,
STATUS
```